# how do i scroll a div while the mouse is down in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

[image]What I want to accomplish is to scroll the indicator in the red bar only while the mouse button is down (see image).

This is my jQuery code:

```
var offset = 0;
var mouseDown = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#RedScroller").mousedown(function() {
        mouseDown = true;
    });

    $("#RedScroller").mouseup(function() {
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    while (mouseDown == true)
    {
        $("#RedSlider").mousemove(function(e) {
            var offset = $(this).offset(); 
            offset = e.pageX - offset.left;
            if (offset <= 255 && offset >= 0)
            {
                $("#RedScroller").css("left", offset);
                $("#ColorDisplay").text(offset);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

But the slider just keeps still.
How can I accomplish this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bebbie7/zf69Q/

Comment: Can you add the jsFiddle?

Comment: The while is only going to fire once when the document is ready, you need to put it in a function or bind it to the mouse down or something.

Comment: Instead of using a while loop, perhaps use a MouseMove event and check if mouse is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your while loop will execute once on DomReady and not everytime the mouse goes down as you need to.

```
$("#RedScroller").mousedown(function() {
    mouseDown = true;
});

$("#RedScroller").mouseup(function() {
     mouseDown = false;
});

$("#RedSlider").mousemove(function(e) {
    if(mouseDown == true) {
        var offset = $(this).offset(); 
        offset = e.pageX - offset.left;
        if (offset <= 255 && offset >= 0)
        {
            $("#RedScroller").css("left", offset);
            $("#ColorDisplay").text(offset);
        }
    }
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/zf69Q/1/

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I did not see this... its actually so easy!